# Optimize Bluetooth LE L2CAP throughput between Linux running bluer l2cat and iOS

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, l2cap

In transferring a raw stream of data over Bluetooth LE L2CAP between Linux and iOS, I get a throughput of approx. 9 kilobyte payload per sec. I expected to be able to transfer approx. 25 kB/s.

How can I investigate and/or optimize on the transfer rate?

**Client Details**

The L2CAP client is an iPhone 13 Pro running iOS 16 using the ["CBL2CAPChannel-Demo"](https://github.com/bluekitchen/CBL2CAPChannel-Demo/tree/master/CBL2CAPChannel-Demo) app over PSM 0x95.

It is essentially using Apple's [open2LCAPChannel(_ PSM:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/2880151-openl2capchannel) method in CBPeripheral.

As far as I see, Apple offers no configuration options for changing connection intervals, MTUs or anything like that. It all seems to be automatic.

**Server Details**

The L2CAP server is a Linux computer running Linux 5.10 using the *bluez* Bluetooth stack.

The test program is the command `l2cat` from Rust's *[bluer-tools](https://github.com/bluez/bluer/tree/master/bluer-tools)*.

I have used `btmon` to examine the exchanged packets, and they seem to be generally either 188 or 243 bytes in length.

Per Apple's recommendation, I have tried setting the connection interval min/max to 15 like so:

```
echo 15 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
echo 15 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval
```

It did not have any effect on throughput.

How can I tell whether the Bluetooth module is using the 1Mbps PHY or the 2Mbps PHY?

I have tested the server on two seperate types of hardware:

1. Raspberry Pi CM4 with its built-in Bluetooth module and an external antennae
2. i.MX 8M Mini computer with an Intel WiFi 6 AX200 module and an external antennae

Note: It was tested with two different types of external antennae, and it was verified that the antennaes were connected properly.